# how to disable select option in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%=f.select :action_item_status,action_item_status%>
```

How can i disable all the option in this select option.

Answer (score 64):

```
<%= f.select :action_item_status, action_item_status, {}, {:disabled => true} %>
```

Comment: Note: If you disable a `<SELECT>` tag in a form, you may need to send the value with a `hidden_field` tag so your controller will receive the current value.

Answer (score 6):

```
f.select :action_item_status, action_item_status, {}, disabled: true
```

As I cant comment to the last comment, your mistake is, that disabled has to be in the fourth not the third param.

So make sure you add a empty one!

Comment: perfect answer with explanations. Only this answer works for me on Rails 4.2.x

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= f.select :status, STATUSES.map{|s| [s.titleize, s]}, { disabled: DISABLED_STATUSES.map{|s| [s.titleize, s]} %>
```